# SQL Server Management Studio 2016 slow to reach splash screen

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

I've got a fast Dell Precision 7720 laptop with a solid state drive, and all my applications load really quickly - apart from Management Studio.  I also had this problem on my previous laptop.

I've read a number of discussions on this - and especially [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/7247/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-sql-management-studio-to-connect) - but none of the solutions work for me. It takes 13 seconds to reach this screen:

[image]

I'm running Windows 10, and the following SQL Server versions:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong?  I'm sure this started happening relatively recently.

Comment: I'd be happy with a fast 13 seconds on my corporate PC (with SSD and 16GB RAM). SSMS is notoriously slow to load unfortunately

Comment: New AV? Any time I see "random new" latency issues that's pretty much the first place I start.

Comment: You are a genius!  It's MalwayreBytes - I've just quit it, and it's solved the problem.  So it looks like I have a choice: get a virus, or load SSMS slowly ...

Comment: @AndyBrown If only I got paid like a genius! Glad my off hand comment helped. In my experience, most people would have just ignored it. :)

Comment: If you don't need that full bloat product, the same Microsoft product team published a much smaller new product, called SQL Operations Studio, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/what-is

Comment: Takes about 120 seconds for it to start on Windows 7

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue on Windows 10 where Management Studio's SSMS.exe would launch but take forever just to get to the splash screen, before any connections; no UI would display.  My fix:

1. Close SSMS.exe
2. Rename *C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0* to *14.0_OLD*
3. Launch SSMS; splash screen and UI come up almost immediately

I had previous crashes of my machine (not Management Studio) so some file may have become corrupted, causing the slow start.

Comment: This worked great for a week or two, but now has gone back to being slow again.  I tried to rename the folder again, but it hasn't helped this time.  SSMS has taken about 2 minutes to load again. :-(

Comment: now up to 20 minutes to get to the splash screen..  I see the SSMS process is running at 24%~ CPU, but there is nothing on the screen to reflect this..  no application windows, etc.  Soooo frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using v18, remove all folders (old ssms versions), and start again.
SSMS create only needed folder, and speed up startup up.